# Node Express CSRF token in not invalidated after logout

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I'm using the standard express CSRF module. It seems to work correctly, except that after logging out and logging in again, it's still possible to use a CSRF token generated in the previous session. I thought it would be enough to invalidate the session - see example of code here, but that's not working:

```
const csrf = require("csurf");
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });

//CSRF protected route
app.post("/editUser",csrfProtection,async function (req, res, next) {
   //Do stuff
});

//Logout route
app.get("/logout", function (req, res) { 
   req.session.destroy(); 
});
```

What do I need to do to make sure CSRF tokens are invalidated on the user logging out?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but using the clearCookie function on both log out and log in routes seems to do the trick, e.g.

```
app.get("/logout", function (req, res) { 
   res.clearCookie("_csrf");
   req.session.destroy(); 
});
```